# Same text but were not equal, how to convert to the same encoding?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

I am having a text processing trouble.

(A) 'khách hàng'

(B) 'khách hàng'

A and B are the same but they're not equals in code. They look like the same, right?

You can see my problem by **press F12 > Console > paste 'khách hàng' === 'khách hàng' > Enter**

May I convert A and B to the same encoding? And How?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check equality of Unicode strings in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097867/how-do-i-check-equality-of-unicode-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the two strings (A) and (B) make use of a different normalization form: `NFC` (Canonical Composition) for (A), `NFD` (Canonical Decomposition) for (B).

(A) `khách hàng`: `U+006B U+0068 U+00E1 U+0063 U+0068 U+0020 U+0068 U+00E0 U+006E U+0067`

(B) `khách hàng`: `U+006B U+0068 U+0061 U+0301 U+0063 U+0068 U+0020 U+0068 U+0061 U+0300 U+006E U+0067`

In order to compare them for equality, both strings must be normalized first to the same form; in JavaScript, this can be achieved through the [normalize()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) method:

```
let A = 'khách hàng';
let B = 'khách hàng';
console.log (A === B); // -> false
console.log (A.normalize ('NFC') === B.normalize ('NFC')); // -> true
console.log (A.normalize ('NFD') === B.normalize ('NFD')); // -> true
```

**Warning**: depending on your web browser, especially in Firefox or Safari, copying or pasting the string (B) may result in string (A); it seems that an unexpected normalization step is performed "behind the scenes"...